# MSD CRM: Get the count of records of all entities in CRM

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I am working on to get the record count of every entity available in the CRM. I have seen so many solutions are available on the internet But I have searched in the database(As we have on-prem) and found one table called **'RecordCountSnapshot'** has the count(and answer to my question). I am wondering can we query that table somehow and get the count.

I have tried using OData Query builder, I am able to prepare a query but unable to get the result.

Query:

[image]

Result:

[image]

We are using CRM 2015 on-prem version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Settings -> Customizations -> Developer Resources -> Service Endpoints -> Organization Data Service`

Open by clicking `/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/`, it is missing the definition for `RecordCountSnapshot`. That means this entity is not serviceable by OData. Even if you modify the other OData query url to use `RecordCountSnapshotSet` you will get 'Not found' error. (I tried in CRM REST builder)

1) As you are in Onpremise, You can use this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Count]
,[RecordCountSnapshotId]
,entityview.ObjectTypeCode, Name
FROM [YOURCRM_MSCRM].[dbo].[RecordCountSnapshot] , EntityView 
where entityview.ObjectTypeCode = RecordCountSnapshot.ObjectTypeCode
and count > 0 order by count desc
```

2) In **Odata Query Designer**, you have **statistics** tab. Use it to get the records count.

Answer (score 1):

One option to get the counts of all entities is to run this SQL query against the MSCRM database:

```
SELECT SO.Name, SI.rows 
FROM sysindexes SI, SysObjects SO 
WHERE SI.id = SO.ID AND SO.Type = 'U' AND SI.indid < 2 
order by rows DESC
```

I have also built a command line app that's in beta testing that runs a count of all entities. If you're interested, let's chat.